# In java class java.util.Iterator interface has been implemented?

Tags: java

I have been asked in an interview that in which java class iterator interface has been implemented where the `hasNext()`, `next()` and `remove()` methods are defined.

Please let me know. This seems critical.

Comment: Have you considered checking out the API docs? It lists which classes implement a given interface.

Answer (score 2):

The **iterator** interface is implemented in **java.util.AbstractList**, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html. Here is an explanation from the documentation: "*Unlike the other abstract collection implementations, the programmer does not have to provide an iterator implementation; the iterator and list iterator are implemented by this class, on top the "random access" methods: get(int index), set(int index, Object element), set(int index, Object element), add(int index, Object element) and remove(int index).*"

The method **iterator()** returns an iterator over the elements in the list. You will also see this method on classes that extend the AbstractList: Vector, ArrayList.

Comment: This seems very similar to the other answer provided by @Kanagavelu Sugumar about a year ago - how does this answer add anything?

Comment: AbstractList doesn't implements Iterator interface; It implements Iterable interface. only iterator()::Iterable.java return type is Iterator.

Answer (score 0):

**java.util.AbstractList** is the abstract class providing implementation for the **Iterable** interface (by implementing List Interface where List extends Collection Ifc; Collection  extends Iterable Ifc).

AbstractList has inner class `private class Itr` which implements `Iterator` Interface, Means providing implementation for `hasNext(), next()` methods here.
So iterator() :: AbstractList method is providing `new Itr()` object for traverse on that collection.

ArrayList, Vector all are sub classes of AbstractList which inherently have access for iterator()::AbstractList API and returning new Iterator object.

Simalarly for Set; **AbstractCollection** is abstract class for iterator implementation.

We do have one more inner class in **java.util.AbstractList**  
i.e 
**`class ListItr extends Itr implements ListIterator`**   
This will allow us to traverse the collection in both direction.